# Create Rackspace Cloudfiles user via API

Tags: architecture, cloud, rackspace, infrastructure, cloudfiles

I can't find any reference anywhere on how to create a user via API for Rackspace Cloudfiles.
I take it it is not possible?
Is there any equivalent function to Amazon AIM API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible.

You would need to use the [Rackspace Identity Service API](http://docs.rackspace.com/auth/api/v2.0/auth-client-devguide/content/QuickStart-000.html). In particular, have a look at the [Users resource API](http://docs.rackspace.com/auth/api/v2.0/auth-client-devguide/content/User_Calls.html). If you want to restrict those users to a product like Cloud Files you'll need to use the [Roles resource API](http://docs.rackspace.com/auth/api/v2.0/auth-client-devguide/content/Role_Calls.html).

It will also be helpful to read up on the [Rackspace Role Based Access Control](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/overview-role-based-access-control-rbac). You'll need to know the [Permissions Matrix for RBAC](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/permissions-matrix-for-role-based-access-control-rbac) if you're assigning roles to your users.